# nginx proxy_pass works via curl but does not work with my browser

Tags: linux, nginx, reverse-proxy

I try to set up a reverse proxy with nginx and added the `proxy_pass` clause - for testing purposes I forward it to google.com. My `nginx.conf` looks like this:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
#include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}


http {
    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    server {
        listen  80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name localhost;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://www.google.com;
        }
    }


    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    #include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    #include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

However, when testing it with `curl http://161.35.216.150`  it works just fine but when I enter the IP in my browser this does not work. The `error.log`does not show any entry and `nginx -t` works well.

my system is:

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

There are some questions around with similar problems, however the solutions provided don't work for me. (e.g. are suse specific or relate to includes that override the conf-file)

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: What is the output of `curl --verbose http://161.35.236.150`? What does the browser show when you navigate to that address?

Comment: Also, have you looked at nginx's proxy_pass configuration? https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/ What if Google doesn't like it because of some extra headers being sent or not being set? From my experience, Google doesn't take kindly to not being able to see everything you're doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check your firewall rules.
Run `sudo ufw status`.

If you don't see this

```
Nginx HTTP                 ALLOW       Anywhere
```

run `sudo ufw allow http`. Then run `sudo ufw reload`.

Are you running `curl http://161.35.216.150` from the shell of  remote machine or local  machine?

This configuration will just redirect you to https://www.google.com.

If you are trying to use this host to change your IP address for searches or create a bounce box, you would have better success with creating socks5 proxy via ssh.

On your local machine using Linux or OS/X, try `ssh -ND 1080 user@remote_server`. 
Configure your browser to use `socks5://localhost:1080`
This is done in the network configuration of your operating system if you use Chrome.

Comment: A firewall blocking port 80 does so regardless of the access tool, browser or `curl`. The server's OS doesn't know or care which application generates the connection request.

Comment: If running a curl command in the person's ssh session on the remote host, the person could get a response.  If  ran on a remote host, he would not get a response using curl or a web browser. ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT would like be the error if it is a firewall issue or the service stopped running. This sounds like a firewall issue to me.

Comment: *If running a curl command in the person's ssh session on the remote host, the person could get a response. If ran on a remote host, he would not get a response* This is a contradiction in itself.

Comment: thank you for all your very helpful comments - it was a firewall issue: ```sudo ufw allow http``` was not allowed. i feel a little embarrassed having overlooked this obvious reason. thanks again!